# KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-286-1ee9b9495dc1> in <module>()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to graph a bar chart with data on covid-19 in Colombia. I made a dataframe with the cities, the number of cases and the date, then I added some aesthetics and a column with the year and the country. But when the code tries to read the dataframe I get this error. I don't know why it doesn't recognize the key

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML

dat=db.pivot_table(values='Casos',index=["Ciudad",'Fecha'],
                   aggfunc={'count'})

dat.reset_index(inplace=True)
dat['Fecha']=dat["Fecha"]

dat

año=[]
for i in range(3927):
  año.append(2020)

group=[]
for k in range(3927):
  group.append('Colombia')

dat['año']=año
dat['group']=group

colors = dict(zip(
    ['Arauca', 'Armenia', 'Barranquilla', 'Bogotá D.C.', 'Bucaramanga',
       'Cali', 'Cartagena de Indias', 'Cúcuta', 'Florencia', 'Ibagué',
       'Inírida', 'Leticia', 'Manizales', 'Medellín', 'Mitú', 'Mocoa',
       'Montería', 'Neiva', 'Pasto', 'Pereira', 'Popayán',
       'Puerto Carreño', 'Quibdó', 'Riohacha', 'San Andrés',
       'San José del Guaviare', 'Santa Marta', 'Sincelejo', 'Tunja',
       'Valledupar', 'Villavicencio', 'Yopal'],
    ["#adb0ff", "#ffb3ff", "#90d595", "#e48381", "#aafbff", "#f7bb5f", "#eafb50",'#c0c0c0','#808080',
     '#ff0000','#ffff00','#808000','#00ff00','#008000','#00ffff','#008080','#000080','#ff00ff',
     '#800080','#f0f8ff','#faebd7','#7fffd4','#f0ffff','#f5f5dc','#ffe4c4','#000000','#8a2be2',
     '#a52a2a','#7fff00','#ff8c00','#cd5c5c','#20b2aa']
))
group_lk = dat.set_index('Ciudad')['group'].to_dict()

dff = dat[dat['año'].eq(2020)].sort_values(by='count', ascending=True).tail(10)
dff

dff.keys()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))

def draw_barchart(current_year):
    dff = dat[dat['año'].eq(current_year)].sort_values(by='count', ascending=True).tail(10)
    ax.clear()
    ax.barh(dff['Ciudad'], dff['count'], color=[colors[group_lk[x]] for x in dff['Ciudad']])
    dx = dff['count'].max() / 200
    for i, (value, name) in enumerate(zip(dff['count'], dff['Ciudad'])):
        ax.text(value-dx, i,     name,           size=14, weight=600, ha='right', va='bottom')
        ax.text(value-dx, i-.25, group_lk[name], size=10, color='#444444', ha='right', va='baseline')
        ax.text(value+dx, i,     f'{value:,.0f}',  size=14, ha='left',  va='center')
    ax.text(1, 0.4, current_year, transform=ax.transAxes, color='#777777', size=46, ha='right', weight=800)
    ax.text(0, 1.06, 'Population (thousands)', transform=ax.transAxes, size=12, color='#777777')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#777777', labelsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.margins(0, 0.01)
    ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-')
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax.text(0, 1.15, 'The most populous cities in the world from 1500 to 2018',
            transform=ax.transAxes, size=24, weight=600, color='#d62929', ha='left', va='top')
    ax.text(1, 0, 'by @pratapvardhan; credit @jburnmurdoch', transform=ax.transAxes, color='#777777', ha='right',
            bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='white'))
    plt.box(False)
    
draw_barchart(2020)
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-286-1ee9b9495dc1> in <module>()
     25     plt.box(False)
     26 
---> 27 draw_barchart(2020)

1 frames
<ipython-input-286-1ee9b9495dc1> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4     dff = dat[dat['año'].eq(current_year)].sort_values(by='count', ascending=True).tail(10)
      5     ax.clear()
----> 6     ax.barh(dff['Ciudad'], dff['count'], color=[colors[group_lk[x]] for x in dff['Ciudad']])
      7     dx = dff['count'].max() / 200
      8     for i, (value, name) in enumerate(zip(dff['count'], dff['Ciudad'])):

KeyError: 'Colombia'
```

Comment: `group.append('Colombia')` Error is legit. What is `Colombia` ?

Comment: It is a list that puts the country of each city